# using min value in where query sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a data in table like this :

```
==============================================================================================
               id                                      idPaper                 Code Sequential
==============================================================================================
1A506D10-9306-495A-9E4E-7081E3D3ACDB    F4CFE90D-0921-4FB7-A236-5420B0892379    0036    2
3DB0FEBF-FBDF-4768-B36A-83AF4FB53E4B    F4CFE90D-0921-4FB7-A236-5420B0892379    0035    1
```

I want display data like this :

```
==============================================================================================
               id                                      idPaper                 Code Sequential
==============================================================================================
3DB0FEBF-FBDF-4768-B36A-83AF4FB53E4B    F4CFE90D-0921-4FB7-A236-5420B0892379    0035    1
1A506D10-9306-495A-9E4E-7081E3D3ACDB    F4CFE90D-0921-4FB7-A236-5420B0892379    0036    2
```

I run my query:

```
select * 
from tablename 
where idPaper = 'F4CFE90D-0921-4FB7-A236-5420B0892379' 
  and min(sequential)
```

but it does not work. Please help me...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `order by`.

```
select *
from tablename 
where idPaper='F4CFE90D-0921-4FB7-A236-5420B0892379'
order by sequential
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to sort the data.  Perhaps you just want:

```
select * 
rom tablename
where idPaper='F4CFE90D-0921-4FB7-A236-5420B0892379' 
order by sequential;
```